# Did the first piano use an equal-tempered or natural scale?

Tags: piano, tuning, history, temperament

Both the piano and the equal-tempered scale were invented in the 1700s (according to Wikipedia, at least). But what I'm wondering is whether the first piano constructed used an equal-tempered scale, or if that was a later modification.

(I have googled the question, but wasn't able to find an answer that way. Maybe my google-fu is low today.)

Comment: If by "natural scale" you mean "just intonation," just intonation as it is typically described today was probably never used to tune keyboard instruments.   If it was, it was certainly no longer in use by the time music specifically for keyboard instruments began to be written.

Comment: Revisiting this question because of an edit to the answer, I realize that the answer to the question title is "no" :-)  But I'd also like to point out that the temperament isn't intrinsic to the instrument.  The first piano used whatever temperament it had been given by its most recent tuner.

Comment: How come this question was tweeted? (Just curious, and didn't see any information about the selection of questions to tweet on the StackMusic twitter account...) [https://twitter.com/StackMusic/status/1593212354057363457]

Comment: There's a lot of noise on the topic over at [Meta.SE], mostly from people suggesting adjustments to the criteria, but the basic explanation is at [How does the twitter bot work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183407/156890).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Not equal temperament

Equal temperament was not generally used in 1700, when Cristofori invented the piano. The following excerpt comes from Edwin M. Good's *Giraffes, Black Dragons, and Other Pianos* (2nd ed. [Stanford University Press, 2001]). The main passage is a footnote, but I've included the preceding sentence as it contains interesting and relevant information.

> In 1795, Johann Jakob Könnicke of Vienna made ... an experimental six-octave piano with six keyboards tuned so that one could play in all keys with "just" tuning.<sup>*</sup>

> <sup>*</sup> Tuning systems were a very intricate problem in this period.... A very early Zumpe piano, a square of 1766, has split black keys so that notes can be tuned to both pitches [e.g., F♯/G♭].... Systems of "equal temperament," ... began to be proposed in the seventeenth century, although it was well into the twentieth before the use of equal temperament became fairly general. (pp. 98-99)

(See also below)

#### Probably some type of meantone temperament

In *Bartolomeo Cristofori and the Invention of the Piano* (Oxford University Press, 2019), Stewart Pollens suggests, indirectly, the possibility Cristofori might have used fifth-comma meantone temperament. The following passage are relevant:

> Cristofori apparently attempted to explain fifth-comma meantone temperament to Scipione Maffei.... Writing in 1666, the theorist Lemmi Rossi indicated that this particular temperament was then in common use, and thus it may have been the tuning that Cristofori preferred. (p. 119)

> The notes Maffei made in connection with the writing of the 1711 article ... shed additional light on Cristofori's ideas regarding temperament.... Cristofori ... seems to be describing, or perhaps advocating, fifth-comma meantone temperament. (p. 240)

With regard to "not equal temperament", a passage from the aforementioned "notes Maffei made" is suggestive:

> That the violin is the only perfect instrument, because it does not have keys and one finds in the whole perfect harmony, that is the flats and sharps each in its place.... That on the violin, you can transpose where you want in any sort of key, without hearing an unpleasant effect, because it has equal fifths, and all just, and it does not fall into false and bad sound, like in other instruments. (p. 240).

Following this passage is the portion referred to above, in which a meantone tuning, probably fifth-comma, is described.

Comment: This says there were lutenists advocating for equal temperament as early as the 1500s. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament#Europe

Comment: What does Good mean by "play in all keys with "just" tuning"?  It's not possible to play even in *one* key with just tuning; it must have been some sort of meantone temperament.

Comment: @Edward: Don't believe anything you read on Wikipedia without following the citations. None of the four citations for that sentence in the article you mention are any good. Some of them are links to lute works that are just composed in all keys; that doesn't imply 12-TET (anymore than Bach's WTC does). The only actual article cited links to some pseudoscience thing that starts out on how women's menstrual cycles are perfectly attuned to the moon's phases. Galilei *did* advocate for a 18:17 fretting that approximates 12-TET, which I guess is the *real* thing that Wikipedia claim is based on.

Comment: @Athanasius What about the citation which appears a few sentences later?  "Lutes, Viols, Temperaments" Mark Lindley ISBN 978-0-521-28883-5. Not that I read it before your comment, but it seems ok.  https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lutes_Viols_Temperaments/oXE5AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=Equal%20Temperament

Comment: @Edward: I'm not saying the general advocacy for something *close* to equal temperament is incorrect for fretted instruments of the time.Obviously that was the case. I'm saying that the first sentence has a bunch of problematic citations--those lutenists were not "advocating" for equal temperament: they wrote pieces in a variety of keys. There's a difference. Galilei *was* advocating for equal temperament (though a practical manner of tuning it at the time was a problem).The point is that the Wikipedia article misrepresents things and offers "citations" that aren't actually proving its claims.

Comment: @phoog I’m very confused by your comment. Of course you can play in one key on an instrument tuned with just intonation - especially if that key is the basis for the intonation! You can play in multiple keys on any instrument regardless of intonation, but unless the tuning system is equal temperament, the different keys will all *sound* different. This is why it used to matter a lot more when a piece was composed "in C# minor" vs "in A minor". The key would have an effect on the sound of the piece.

Comment: @ToddWilcox well yes, you can play in any key in any temperament, but it will not necessarily be well tuned.  If you tune a keyboard in just intonation then one of the fifths in the diatonic scale of the key to which you've tuned it (most commonly the fifth between the second and sixth scale degrees) will sound like this: https://en.xen.wiki/w/40/27.  So yes, if you want one of your diatonic chords to have that for its fifth, you can use just intonation to tune your keyboard.  Most people don't.  I don't think anyone saying "just intonation sounds great in one key" has ever actually tried it.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add a short paragraph at the end describing the development of unequal "circulating" temperaments during the 18th century, just to underscore that equal temperament didn't come directly after fractional-comma meantone temperaments. Some had already been devised by the time of Cristofori's invention of the piano, and the others were mostly published around the same time. Even if he didn't use them, the people playing his instruments surely did.

Comment: (Also, meantone temperament being popular more than 30 years before the first piano is not necessarily compelling evidence, though Cristofori was born in 1655, so the 1660s were important formative years for him.  In other words, there are two points: Cristofori's preferred temperament probably gives us the literal answer to this question but that doesn't necessarily mean much musicologically speaking, and keyboard instruments of the time weren't manufactured to "use" specific temperaments.)

Comment: @phoog For what it’s worth, I have played in many different tunings/temperaments, including just intonation.

Comment: @ToddWilcox on a keyboard?  How did you deal with the 40/27 fifth?

Comment: @phoog It sounds the way it sounds. Another way to answer that question is "the same way I deal with no intervals in equal temperament being truly consonant". Personally I think Werkmeister III sounds great on piano, *because* of the intervals not being equal. To a lesser extent the same is true about just intonation. So another way to answer your question is, "there's nothing to deal with - there's nothing 'wrong' with a 40/27 fifth."

Comment: @ToddWilcox I don't know what music you're playing, but as far as I am concerned, for most music there is plenty wrong with a 40:27 fifth.  It's certainly clear that musicians in the Renaissance agreed with this, because as soon as interest arose in the 5:4 major third they started using meantone tuning.